# How can I turn off the login theme in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, login, repair

How do I turn off the login theme in Windows 7 so it looks like a Windows 2000/XP plain login screen? Like this:

[image: XP Log-in]

[image: Windows 2000]

Comment: Do you mean the login picture? The blue one?

Comment: He wants the login dialog, where you enter your user name and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try [this tutorial](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-security/enable-ctrlaltdelete-screen-in-vista/), which is applicable to Windows 7.  It shows you how to revert to the classic "CTRL + ALT + DELETE" login.

Comment: still seems to be themed though :(

Comment: I think that method is the closest u can get with the new Win6.x operating systems...

Answer (score 2):

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/89812-logon-username-password.html

It will get you close, but this is how vista/7 does it.